# How to let a bot post/send a message every 5 minutes or because of another event?

Tags: python, bots, discord.py

I thought that would be a simple task but somehow i can even mess this up. 
So i just want to have my bot send a message (to troll my friends) a specific message every 5 minutes. 
So i found this which doesnt work or any other code. I dont even get an error message. So im pretty much clueless, which sucks.

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    counter = 0
    channel = discord.Object(id='channel_id_here')
    while not client.is_closed:
        counter += 1
        await client.send_message(channel, counter)
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
client.run('token')
```

Anyway here is my boiled down code, without all of the Bot commands.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot, has_permissions

import secrets
import numpy as np
import re

TOKEN = 'mytokenasastring'
BOT = Bot(command_prefix='!')
#... some commands for my bot for my friends and myself
BOT.loop.create_task(my_background_task())
BOT.run(TOKEN)
```

So i just added the above code like this

```
async def my_background_task():
await BOT.wait_until_ready()
counter = 0
channel = discord.Object(id='mytestchannelidasastring') #i also tried as int but also doenst work
while not BOT.is_closed:
    counter += 1
    await BOT.send_message(channel, counter)
    await asyncio.sleep(60) # task runs every 60 seconds
```

then vs code tells my Bot doenst have a send_message method. so i change the code of the send_message to this

```
await channel.send(counter)
```

But now i get the warning/error form VS code that channel doenst have a send method so i get the (real?!) channel like this

```
BOT.get_channel(id='mychannelidasstring')
```

and it still doesn't work or i dont get any kind of error message of any kind... pls help or i will go mad....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you're using some of the old async's (v0.16.x) docs/tutorials, which can be seen from `send_message()` and writing IDs as strings. I'd recommend you try to find more recent tutorials and read the recent docs instead.

See [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html) for all the major changes from then into the most recent version, rewrite (v1.x)

As for your code, here is what it should look like:

```py
async def my_background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready() # ensures cache is loaded
    counter = 0
    channel = client.get_channel(id=112233445566778899) # replace with target channel id
    while not client.is_closed():
        counter += 1
        await channel.send(counter)
        await asyncio.sleep(60) # or 300 if you wish for it to be 5 minutes

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')
    client.loop.create_task(my_background_task()) # best to put it in here

client.run("token")
```

---

**References:**

- [Rewrite docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)
- [`Client.wait_until_ready()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_until_ready)
- [`Client.get_channel()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)
- [`TextChannel.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.send)
- [`Client.is_closed()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.is_closed)
- [`asyncio.sleep()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping)
- [`loop.create_task()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.create_task)

Comment: @Tollpatsch Glad to hear it - happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Try using [`discord.tasks.loop`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html?highlight=tasks#discord.ext.tasks.loop).

```py
from discord.ext import tasks

counter = 0

@tasks.loop(minutes=1.0, count=None)
async def my_background_task():
    global counter
    channel = BOT.get_channel(123456789) # channel id as an int
    counter += 1
    await channel.send(f'{counter}')
my_background_task.start()
```

to loop your troll function every minute.

Comment: thanks you too, the other comment was faster but yours with f'' is also a nice solution. Thanks mate :)